# Is it a good idea to use ESLint and stylelint together in the same project

Tags: eslint, lint, stylelint

Does ESLint and Stylelint do the same thing (linting) the project or is one used specifically for certain files? Can I use them both in the same project? Is it a good idea to use more than one linter in general in the same project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be totally appropriate to pair ESLint and Stylelint together. ESLint is for JavaScript, and Stylelint is for CSS.

Generally, I would make sure you're only using one linter per language, since you don't want them fighting with each other; however, as you can see above, it's quite common to use multiple linters for projects that use multiple languages.

Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: well actually there is `stylelint-config-styled-components` for linting css literals in javascript/typescript files with stylelint